# jQuery function (toggling src attr of the img)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I kind of not familiar with all that JS stuff and everything but today I need to use some jQ magic and I read a couple of articles and here's what I've done:

```
$('.thumb_img').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('img/', 'img/full/'));
})
```

Everything works perfectly but I need to make it toggling. The basic idea of this function is to change the src of the image user clicked (just add a "/full" in the path) and if clicked already modificated image again, delete "/full" from the path.

I really have no idea how to make it.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
$( '.thumb_img' ).click( function () {
    var src = this.src;

    if ( src.indexOf( '/full/' ) !== -1 ) {
        src = src.replace( '/full/', '/' ); 
    } else {
        src = src.replace( 'img/', 'img/full/' );
    }

    this.src = src;
});
```

---

Event delegation:

```
$( '#images' ).delegate( '.thumb_img', 'click', function () {
    var src = this.src;

    if ( src.indexOf( '/full/' ) !== -1 ) {
        src = src.replace( '/full/', '/' ); 
    } else {
        src = src.replace( 'img/', 'img/full/' );
    }

    this.src = src;
});
```

where `#images` selects the `<div id="images">` element that contains all the images.

Comment: There are dozens of them, but everything works very fast, smooth and just as planned, I don't think that changing anything in working script is a good idea but I'll appreciate a little explanation of your point (what's event delegation?)

Comment: @Adiost666 Instead of binding event handlers to all IMG elements, you just bind one event handler on a common ancestor (usually the DIV that contains all those images). The code changes only slightly, but the performance benefit is considerable. I've updated my answer with an example...

Comment: Thanks, Sime! Everything works faster with your new code. I owe you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.thumb_img').click(function() {
    //Store your src value so you don't need to get it again.
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    //Determine whether the image is currently "full"
    var full = src.indexOf('full/') > -1; 
    //If it's full, remove it, otherwise, put it in the src.
    src = full ? src.replace('img/full/', 'img/') : src.replace('img/', 'img/full/');
    //Set your SRC value
    $(this).attr('src', src); 
})
```

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work. Nothing happens when clicking an image at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumb_img').not('.state').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('img/', 'img/full/')).toggleClass('.state');
})
$('.thumb_img.state').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('img/full/', 'img/')).toggleClass('.state');
})
```

You can use a class toggle.